# Efficient permutation of given ranking that preserves given distance

Tags: permutations

[Ranked Biased Overlap (RBO)](http://www.williamwebber.com/research/papers/wmz10_tois.pdf) is a metric for comparing two rankings and is used when the sizes of the given rankings are different and/or the elements that they carry are not the same. Ranked Biased Distance (RBD = 1 - RBO) is the distance metric emanating from RBO. A simple demonstration of the metric can be found [here](https://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/comparing-ranked-list/), along with a link to an implementation in Python.

Currently, I want to find an efficient way of calculating the "inverse" of RBO. Typically, RBO is a function like the following:

```
double rbo(List<A> rankingA, List<B> rankingB)
```

The `double` value returned, is the RBO value of rankings `rankingA` and `rankingB`. I want to implement the following method:

```
List<A> generateRanking(List<A> rankingA, double rbo)
```

which given a ranking (`rankingA`) and an RBO value (`rbo`), it generates a random permutation of `rankingA`, that its RBO value with the initial ranking is `rbo`. Apart from a trial-and-error approach, in which I randomly permute `rankingA` until I meet `rbo`, can you think of a better way (more computationally efficient) of doing so?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  1. Can you give a self-contained definition of the RBO metric, in the question?  The link you provide is to a paper that doesn't appear to be freely available to the public.  2. Do you require that the random permutation be uniformly distributed over all permutations whose RBO value with the initial ranking is `rbo`?  Or can it be any random distribution (not necessarily uniform)?

Comment: @D.W. thank you for the welcome message. 1. I have edited my question to contain a link to a blog post that contains a visual explanation, along with python code of RBO. 2. It can be any random distribution, since uniform search might end up too computationally expensive.

Comment: In particular, can it be a random distribution supported on a single element?

Comment: Well, it can be, but I am afraid that might be too limiting. For instance, the desired RBO might be too low or too high with a single element permutation. But, I assume that would be a good place to start

Comment: So based on your comments, it sounds like we can rephrase your question as: "given an initial ranking and a RBO value, output any permutation whose RBO value with the initial ranking is the desired value".  It appears there's no need for the output to be random in any sense; it can be arbitrarily chosen by the algorithm.  If I haven't understood correctly, I hope you'll correct that and clear up my confusion.

Comment: I still think it would be useful to include a self-contained specification of RBO in this question itself. If the link to that page stops working, then the question becomes not understandable.  Also, that link doesn't appear to contain a specification of RBO.  A Python implementation is not a good specification of the metric; not everyone here reads Python.  I suggest you edit the question to include a self-contained definition of the RBO metric, since it is so central to your question.